# Vectorization, 7-bit encoding

Tags: c#, vectorization, .net-core

I was curious how vectorization works and how to write suck code. To start simple I choose 7-bit encoding as my test suspect. I'm not expecting improved throughput in any way. My implementation works just fine, until we go over 2^31 due to compare not doing unsigned comparison. I would like to know how this could be tackled. Looking for some feedback, hints & improvements!

Here is my implementation

```
internal static class VariableInt
{
    internal static void Write7BitEncodedVector(uint value, Span<byte> output)
    {
        //Constants
        Vector128<uint> shiftBy = VariableInt.ReadVector<uint>(VariableInt.SHIFT);
        Vector128<byte> shuffle = VariableInt.ReadVector<byte>(VariableInt.SHUFFLE);
        Vector128<uint> mask = VariableInt.ReadVector<uint>(VariableInt.MASK);

        //A, B, C, D
        Vector128<uint> input = Vector128.Create(value);

        //A, B >> 7, C >> 14, D >> 21
        Vector128<uint> shift = Avx2.ShiftRightLogicalVariable(input, shiftBy);

        //If greter than or equal to 0x00000080, 0x00004000, 0x00200000, 0x10000000
        Vector128<int> compareResult = Sse2.CompareGreaterThan(shift.AsInt32(), mask.AsInt32());

        Vector128<uint> or = Sse2.And(compareResult.AsUInt32(), mask); //Get bit on 0x80
        Vector128<uint> final = Sse2.Or(shift, or); //Merge the "continue" flag, 0x80

        //Map every ints first byte to one integer
        Vector128<byte> shuffled = Ssse3.Shuffle(final.AsByte(), shuffle);

        ref byte outputRef = ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(output);
        ref uint outputRefAsUint = ref Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(output));

        //Writes the shuffled int to the output
        outputRefAsUint = shuffled.AsUInt32().GetElement(0);

        //7-Bit encoding can have 5 bytes, write the last byte manually
        output[4] = (byte)(value >> 28);
    }

    private static Vector128<T> ReadVector<T>(ReadOnlySpan<sbyte> data) where T : struct => Unsafe.As<T, Vector128<T>>(ref Unsafe.As<sbyte, T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(data)));

    private static ReadOnlySpan<sbyte> SHIFT => new sbyte[]
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, //1u >> 0
        7, 0, 0, 0, //1u >> 7
        14, 0, 0, 0, //1u >> 14
        21, 0, 0, 0 //1u >> 21
    };

    private static ReadOnlySpan<sbyte> MASK => new sbyte[]
    {
        -128, 0, 0, 0, //0x80
        -128, 0, 0, 0, //0x80
        -128, 0, 0, 0, //0x80
        -128, 0, 0, 0 //0x80
    };

    private static ReadOnlySpan<sbyte> SHUFFLE => new sbyte[]
    {
        0, 4, 8, 12,
        -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1
    };
}
```

And the point of vectorization is to improve throughput so lets throw the benchmarks too! Nothing interesting here really. Tested on i7-7700HQ.

```
|        Method |     Value |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|-------------- |---------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
| WriteUnrolled |         0 | 6.614 ns | 0.1574 ns | 0.1395 ns |
| WriteUnrolled |       128 | 7.523 ns | 0.1718 ns | 0.1607 ns |
| WriteUnrolled |     16384 | 7.697 ns | 0.1244 ns | 0.1164 ns |
| WriteUnrolled |   2097152 | 8.259 ns | 0.1460 ns | 0.1366 ns |
| WriteUnrolled | 268435456 | 8.857 ns | 0.0888 ns | 0.0787 ns |

|      Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|------------ |---------:|----------:|----------:|
| WriteVector | 7.441 ns | 0.1753 ns | 0.1640 ns |
```

For the curious, the JITted assembly is as follows:

```
mov         r8,1A4F0843780h  
vmovupd     xmm0,xmmword ptr [r8]  
mov         r8,1A4F0843790h  
vmovupd     xmm1,xmmword ptr [r8]  
mov         r8,1A4F0843770h  
vmovupd     xmm2,xmmword ptr [r8]  
vmovd       xmm3,ecx  
vpbroadcastd xmm3,xmm3  
vpsrlvd     xmm0,xmm3,xmm0  
vpcmpgtd    xmm3,xmm0,xmm2  
vpand       xmm2,xmm3,xmm2  
vpor        xmm0,xmm0,xmm2  
vpshufb     xmm0,xmm0,xmm1  
vmovd       r8d,xmm0  
mov         dword ptr [rax],r8d  
cmp         edx,4
jbe         00007FFC21009B31  #Bounds Check
shr         ecx,1Ch  
mov         byte ptr [rax+4],cl  
add         rsp,28h  
ret
```

Comment: Please don't change your code once answers start coming in. That gets confusing very fast for other users passing by. If you have a new version of your code you'd like to get reviewed, please post a new question. Feel free to include a link to this question for extra context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My implementation works just fine, until we go over 2^31 due to compare not doing unsigned comparison.

The "incompleteness" of the set of comparisons is an old problem, and the workarounds are also old. Here are some options, with different trade-offs:

- `x >=u y` -> `max_u(x, y) == x`. With SSE4.1 or later, PMAXUD exists, so this is supported. It's greater than or equal, so the constants need to be adjusted.
- `x >u y` -> `(x ^ INT_MIN) >s (y ^ INT_MIN)`. This even worked back in MMX. Might be considered "more strange". The XOR can be replaced by addition or subtraction, which may be useful if that results opportunities to merge those operations, but here it would not and then XOR is faster on average (as in, across different CPUs: Haswell can execute `pxor` on p015 but `paddd` only on p15, Ryzen has a similar sort of deal, for Skylake it doesn't matter).

Only in AVX512 was `vpcmpud` (with a comparison predicate operand) added.

> ```
> vmovd        xmm3,ecx  
> vpbroadcastd xmm3,xmm3
> ```

This pattern comes from `Vector128.Create(value)`, it may be fine but if `value` originally comes from memory then it would be better to try to get it broadcasted directly from memory: broadcast-from-memory is "free" (no cost on top of the load itself) which `vmovd` and `vpbroadcastd` on top of the load are not (obviously, they're something rather than nothing). You could pass a pointer and use `Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector128`. That wouldn't be good if the value didn't come from memory though, forcing a store/reload isn't worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By mentioning the max value I got an idea, what if I instead checked for min values and then Or them to the final value and indeed, this works for all values! By doing this I also was able to get rid of the extra `vandpd` instruction.

Also regarding the Avx2.ShiftRightLogicalVariable, I'm shifting the values by multiplication to seven. I don't think the fixed-count shifts can do this? The constants are at bottom if u didn't notice.

Comment: Regarding the `vmovd` and `vpbroadcastd` pattern, I did recognize it but had no idea what was the cause. Changed it to `Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector128` but I don't think that has any difference.

Overall after all the changes benchmarks only show noise, nothing drastic.

Comment: @Joni taking the address of an operand and then loading from it is almost always bad, it will tend to get passed in a register so that forces it to be stored just to reload it, possibly resulting in a load/store/reload sequence. Passing in the value *by pointer* may help, depending on where it originally comes from.

Comment: Passing the operand produces `lea rcx,[rsp+30h]` followed by `vpbroadcastd xmm3,dword ptr [rsp+30h]` while passing by reference (ref uint) gives `mov r8,1BFA5C837E0h` followed by `vmovupd xmm2,xmmword ptr [r8]` and `mov r8,rcx` while passing by pointer (uint*) gives `vpbroadcastd xmm3,dword ptr [rcx]` but that requires pinning the memory, when it comes from the heap

Comment: Actually, I made few overloads for passing by value and passing by ref which points to method that gets a uint* pointer. Looks like the JIT can better optimize out the overloads and inline them accordingly without extra instructions in between. Nothing catches my eye anymore at least and I think all the optimizations that can be done are there.

Comment: The benchmarks show small improvement, around 3-5% (few instructions got cut off at least) so that could be more than just noise, nothing big but I'm happy